# File_put_contents UTF-8?

Tags: php

Can you help me? This code below have no errors, but the image name is not in UTF-8 format, so, what should I do?

```
$url=IMAGE URL TO DOWNLOAD
$contents=@file_get_contents($url);
if ($contents) {
$fileName = "".$name1."-".$date."";
$fileExt = ".png";
file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/images/dw/".$fileName."".$fileExt."", $contents);
echo "Success";
}
```

Also, I already tried opening the file in Notepad++ and changing the format, didn't worked... And tried using:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

Didn't helped too...

Comment: Lots of unnecesary quotes like `""` in that code are just serving to confuse the issue

Comment: Sorry I'm new in PHP, thanks for the tip! I'll try to fix it asap

Comment: Can you show us what is the value of $name1?

Comment: $name1 = Larry Gaye o comissário de bordo

Answer (score 0):

Try [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

In your case it would be:

```
$fileName = utf8_encode($name1) ."-" . $date;
```

Comment: @spycode Remove the @ from `@file_get_contents($url);` if you want to see errors.

Comment: What I meant is that the file is being saved with non-utf8 charset